# Factory_girl or machinist?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tdd, bdd

Are you using factory_girl or machinist for stubbing/mocking in Rails tests?

Comment: No. I'm not doing any stubbing/mocking, and I'm not using Rails.

Comment: @andrew-grimm Well played, sir.

Comment: What is the purpose of this question? Voting to close.

Comment: @andrew. what is your problem?

Comment: @ajsie: I answered your question literally. If the answer isn't helpful, it may be a sign that you didn't ask the correct question.

Comment: @andrew grimm. If that was indeed an appropriate answer, why not post it as an answer instead. Sorry for my badly formulated question, but what a bad attitude (reading between the lines). If someone asked you something downtown and it was badly formulated but you understood what he/she wants, you just walk away or do you choose to help that person out? Damn it humans, stop being coders only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  Those libraries are not stubbing/mocking libraries*.

Both Machinist and Factory Girl are libraries that help you instantiate objects in your tests without the fuss of [fixtures](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Fixtures.html).  After you've instantiated an object using one of these libraries, you might then mock or stub methods on that object, but Factory Girl and Machinist wouldn't have anything to do with that.

Check out [Mocha](http://rubydoc.info/gems/mocha/0.9.8/frames) for stubbing/mocking.

*[Factory Girl has a stubbing feature](http://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/418cbfbb5fb0acf5e90558027cc4e697208fb6f7/lib/factory_girl/proxy/stub.rb) that's specifically for stubbing models, but nothing for general stubbing/mocking.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using factory_girl.  I haven't tried machinist so I can't compare the two, but I'm quite happy with factory_girl.